# Angular Filter not working on ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am new in AngularJs. I have three Select boxes with ng-options. It was working fine before adding filter.

```
<td style="33%">
    <select ng-options="car.BaseStation for car in UnUsedCars | orderBy:'BaseStation'" ng-model="selected.BaseStation">
        <option value="">All Locations</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td style="33%">
    <select ng-options="car.CarType for car in UnUsedCars | filter: selected.BaseStation | orderBy:'CarType'" ng-model="selected.CarType">
        <option value="">All Car Types</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td style="33%">
    <select ng-options="car.Color for car in UnUsedCars | filter: selected.BaseStation | filter: selected.CarType | orderBy:'Color'" ng-model="selected.Color">
        <option value="">All Car Colors</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

The second Select box is expected to act according to the first select box value and third one is expected to work according to the first and second.

The data to these 3 select came from an array of objects 'UnUsedCars'.
A sample input is as follows:

```
[{
    "CarType" : "Audi",
    "Color" : "White",
    "BaseStation" : "Canada"
},
{
    "CarType" : "BMW",
    "Color" : "White",
    "BaseStation" : "U.S.A"
},
{
    "CarType" : "Benz",
    "Color" : "Black",
    "BaseStation" : "Canada"
}]
```

My JS is as follows

```
       scope.selected = {
            BaseStation: null,
            CarType: null,
            Color: null
        };

        scope.$watch('selected.BaseStation', function() {
            scope.selected.CarType = null;
        });

        scope.$watch('selected.BaseStation', 'selected.CarType', function() {
            scope.selected.Color = null;
        });
```

What are the mistakes I made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `$watch` or anything like this.

Well, actually your `ngModel` is receiving an object from each `<select>`, but since you want to get only the property you should use the `as` syntax, as below:

```
<select ng-options="car.BaseStation as car.BaseStation for car in UnUsedCars | orderBy: 'BaseStation'" ng-model="selected.BaseStation">
```

Take a look on the *snippet*:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.UnUsedCars = [  
       {  
          "CarType":"Audi",
          "Color":"White",
          "BaseStation":"Canada"
       },
       {  
          "CarType":"BMW",
          "Color":"White",
          "BaseStation":"U.S.A"
       },
       {  
          "CarType":"Benz",
          "Color":"Black",
          "BaseStation":"Canada"
       }
    ];
  }
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="33%">
        <select ng-options="car.BaseStation as car.BaseStation for car in UnUsedCars | orderBy: 'BaseStation'" ng-model="selected.BaseStation">
          <option value="">All Locations</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="33%">
        <select ng-options="car.CarType as car.CarType for car in UnUsedCars | filter: selected.BaseStation | orderBy: 'CarType'" ng-model="selected.CarType">
          <option value="">All Car Types</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="33%">
        <select ng-options="car.Color as car.Color for car in UnUsedCars | filter: selected.BaseStation | filter: selected.CarType | orderBy: 'Color'" ng-model="selected.Color">
          <option value="">All Car Colors</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. Can you please suggest a way to make it work with "All Locations", "All Car Types" and "All Colors"..

Comment: Glad that helped :) Hmm.. it happens because you were initializing the data. Just remove as I did and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to avoid `filter` as they mutate your `ngModel.viewModel` (value you passed).

I suggest you to just write `ng-show='ctrl.isBaseStation(car)'` for `<option>` under select.

It is simple approach that does not require any additional filtering. Filtering itself is heavy process that parses all your data with stripping out filtered results. The result you want to achieve - to do not display item, but not to mutate original data set.

P.S. Re-rendering options using `ng-show` (hiding/showing) is much faster than re-calculating all your data set.